# How to change active tab on navbar when scrolling until a component is visible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a navBar with multiple tabs which I can click and it scrolls me to the component (scrollToComponent), it also sets that tab as the active one.

I also want to do the oposite, scroll and when a component is visible it should mark the corresponding tab as the active one.

I found [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/), that demonstrates exactly what I need, but it uses Jquery, and the items that it scrolls to are not components, and all of them have the same height.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

function onScroll(event){
var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
$('#menu-center a').each(function () {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
        $('#menu-center ul li a').removeClass("active");
        currLink.addClass("active");
    }
    else{
        currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Replying myself since it can be useful for someone on the future:

I made [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-intersection-observer-d7h5m?file=/src/index.tsx) example using [react-intersection-observer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intersection-observer).

It has a custom hook that lets you know if the element is visible, then you would have to compare which element is on top, so you can decide which tab you want to set as the active one.